# GridView Edit Button Deleting Row

Tags: sql, .net, gridview, edit

I'm currently working on creating a replacement front-end for modification of a couple database tables one of our users maintains.  The tables that are maintained using this interface provide data to other applications my teammates and I create.

In using the front end that is currently in place, the user who maintains this data has, on occasion, created rows of data consisting of multiple permutations on a CorpName for a given CorpNum (be it through typos, including different, additional information in the CorpName field, etc.).  This leads to our applications which query the data presenting our users with multiple selections for the same corporation, which is often confusing.

As such, I am looking to provide the user who maintains this data with the ability to modify CorpNames to fix typos or to sync up some of the CorpNames so that each CorpNum only has one corresponding CorpName associated to it.

One of the controls I'm using is a GridView control that I've bound to a sql datasource whose Select command is the following:

**select distinct CorpNum, CorpName from TableName order by CorpNum asc**

I've made this GridView sortable (per request), and I've also placed an Edit button in the leftmost column of the GridView.  The Update command for this Edit operation is the following stored procedure:

UPDATE TableName SET CorpName = @CorpName WHERE CorpNum = @CorpNum

The odd behavior I'm seeing is the following:

When I click on the Edit button for a row that may have the same CorpNum as another row in the GridView control, the row is automatically removed from the GridView AND from the database table (I'm using a copy for testing, so there's no real threat there).  I could see something like this happening if I was to, say, actually EDIT the contents of the cell to make the CorpName of the row I selected the same as the CorpName of a different row with the same CorpNum (as the output of the resulting distinct select would remove one row), but I haven't changed anything, nor have I clicked the Update button.  This is what I find strange.

Any thoughts?  Please feel free to ask for any clarification, etc., of course.

The SqlDataSource markup is below.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsCorporationInfo" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString %>
    SelectCommand="select distinct CorpNum,CorpName from Distribution_xx order by CorpNum asc"
    onselecting="sdsCorporationInfo_Selecting" 
    UpdateCommand="sp_XXUpdateCorporationInfo" 
    UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="CorpNum" Type="Decimal" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="CorpName" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The update stored procedure code is here:

```
        PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_XXUpdateCorporationInfo] 
        @CorpNum numeric,
        @CorpName varchar(40)
        AS
        UPDATE Distribution_xx SET CorpName = @CorpName WHERE CorpNum = @CorpNum
```

The GridView markup is here:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCorporationInfo" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="sdsCorporationInfo" Visible="False"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
    onrowediting="gvCorporationInfo_RowEdit"
    onrowupdated="gvCorporationInfo_RowUpdate"
    onrowupdating="gvCorporationInfo_RowUpdating"
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Corp #" SortExpression="CorpNum">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CorpNum") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CorpNum") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Corp Name" SortExpression="CorpName">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CorpName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CorpName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here are the events in the code behind (there's not much there):

```
    protected void gvCorporationInfo_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        gvCorporationInfo.DataBind();
    }
    protected void gvCorporationInfo_RowEdit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvCorporationInfo.UpdateRow(e.NewEditIndex, true);
    }
```

An idea of the GridView content at runtime is below:

```
            Corp #  Corp Name
    Edit    33  Corp Name 1
    Edit    37  Corp Name 2
    Edit    48  Corp Name 3
    Edit    48  Corp Name Three
    Edit    51  Corp Name 4
    Edit    53  Corp Name 5
    Edit    56  Corp Name 6
    Edit    57  Corp Name 7
    Edit    60  Corp Name 8
    Edit    61  Corp Name 9
    Edit    63  Corp Name 10
    Edit    64  Corp Name 11
    Edit    65  Corp Name 12
    Edit    66  Corp Name 13
    Edit    68  Corp Name 14
    Edit    70  Corp Name 15
    Edit    71  Corp Name 16
    Edit    71  Corp Name Sixteen
```

TIA

Comment: We might need more complete code from front end, code behind, and stored procedure to get a more complete picture. Also, I would recommend using the SQL Profiler to monitor your db and capture the commands that execute when you hit that edit button from your app. That might help show something unexpected and give you some direction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just updated my post with c# code behind, markup, the stored procedure, and an example of the gridview contents at runtime.

Comment: I still recommend using SQL Profiler to see what's being sent. I'd be happy to walk you through that if you've never used it. It's been the best troubleshooting tool ever for me. Something else to consider, the parameter data types. I've had weird problems trying to define data types in ASP like this. I typically just declare the parameter in the SP as varchar() and then send it as a string. Then I use a convert or cast inside SQL to line up types. This has been effective for me. Another possible solution would be to create your connection and execute your SP from the code behind instead.

Comment: I have just confirmed that, if I change my select query to

Comment: Set your update parameters in your ASP page as  `<asp:Parameter Name="CorpNum">`  and then in your SQL SP declare it as varchar and then then make your WHERE `CAST(CorpNum AS INT) = @CorpNum` and see if that makes a difference. Otherwise, if you're still having problems and want an example of how to set this up in the codebehind instead, just let me know.

Comment: I just tried casting a varchar to an int and taking the datatype attribute out of the asp:Parameter tag. I'm still seeing the same behavior. The code behind route will probably be the way to go.  I can write DAL code to call the stored procedure.  I just need to know how to, subsequently, bind that data to the selected row in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with what's below.

The ASP markup, note the onrowediting that's been added to refer to the event in the codebehind. Also, in the columns the first one is a CommandField button. The auto generate edit is replaced with this so the selected row can use the codebehind event. This is what has worked for me, and I hope it's useful. If nothing else, maybe it'll spark something an idea that helps you out. And once more, DO run the profiler to see what is being sent to the SQL server. It's a great way to find data mismatches and odd bits that give you trouble. It could be something terribly small, and that would help you spot it.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCorporationInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="sdsCorporationInfo"
    onselectedindexchanged="gvCorporationInfo_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    DataKeyNames="CorpNum" onrowdatabound="Grid_OnRowDataBound" 
    onrowediting="gvCorporationInfo_RowEditing" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" EditText="  Edit  " />
<asp:BoundField>...all your boundfields here
```

The ASP datasource connection

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsCorporationInfo" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString %>
SelectCommand="select distinct CorpNum,CorpName from Distribution_xx order by CorpNum asc"
onselecting="sdsCorporationInfo_Selecting" 

<UpdateParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CorpName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CorpNum" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In your codebehind

```
    protected void gvCorporationInfo_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionstring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("DatabaseName.dbo.sp_XXUpdateCorporationInfo", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorpNum", (String)gvCorporationInfo.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorpName", (String)gvCorporationInfo.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value);


    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    con.Close();

    gvCorporationInfo.DataBind();
}
```

I apologize if I've mistyped anything.

Comment: I'll try it out, and no apologies are necessary.  You've no idea how much I appreciate the help.